# jq create unique keys from json duplicates

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to transform a json file, it looks like this so far after extracting what I need:

```
{
  "title": "title 1",
  "description": "desc 1",
  "message": "msg 1",
  "region": "region 1",
  "resource": "resource 1"
}
{
  "title": "title 1",
  "description": "desc 1",
  "message": "msg 1",
  "region": "region 2",
  "resource": "resource 2"
}
```

I would like to transform it into

```
{
  "title": "title 1",
  "description": "desc 1",
  "message": "msg 1",
  "data": [
           {"region 1":"resource 1"},
           {"region 2":"resource 2"}
          ]
}
```

My idea would be to transform the json and make title, description, message that are repeating unique (thus removing the duplicate) while keeping the changing region and resources into a data object.

I tried group_by(.title) it gives me an error "Cannot index string with string "title", I wanted to do group_by(.title,.description,.message).

I tried unique_by also getting errors.

My current query is

```
jq '.[] | {title : .title, description : .description, message : .message, data: [{region: .region, resource: .resource}] } | group_by(.title,.description,.message)'
```

Comment: `{"region 1","resource 1" }` doesn't make sense, you have an object braces but a list inside.

Comment: Thanks you are right, I would have a list of dictionary, with the keys being region 1, region 2 and the values being the resource 1, resource 2. Changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
jq -s '[.[]
        | { title : .title,
            description : .description,
            message : .message,
            data: [{region: [.region], resource: [.resource]}]
          }
       ]
       | group_by(.title, .descripiton, .message)
       | .[]
       | { title: .[0].title,
           description: .[0].description,
           message: .[0].message,
           data:{
               region: [.[].data[].region | add],
               resource: [.[].data[].resource | add]
           }}'
```

Comment: Thank you not sure what is going on in your code but it gives me this error 'Cannot index string with string "title" '

Answer (score 0):

The following is a succinct variant of @choroba's program that may be of interest as it will preserve all keys of the JSON objects apart from the two that are to be consolidated:

```
map( . + {data: [{region: [.region], resource: [.resource]}]}
     | del(.region, .resource) )
| group_by(.title, .description, .message)[]
| .[0] +
    { data: {
        region:   [.[].data[].region   | add],
        resource: [.[].data[].resource | add]
      }
    }
```

It should of course also be used with the -s command-line option.